# How to plot a nonlinear equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, equation

I need to plot this equation : `(y)/[(4*3.14*10^-7)*(1+(4200/(1+0.03(y^8.2))^0.5))]`
on the interval `y=0` to `y=3`

I tried this

```
y=0:0.5:1:1.5:2:2.5:3;
x=(y)./((4*3.14*10.^-7)*(1+(4200./(1+0.03*y.^8.2).^0.5)));
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `plot` is fine, only your `y` is defined problematically: the syntax is `var=from:step:to`, no additional colons needed. So you either say

```
y=[0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3];
```

or, what's much better,

```
y=0:0.5:3;
```

or, what's equivalent now,

```
y=linspace(0,3,7);
```

Note that the last form will make it easy for you to produce a finer graph of your function (since `plot` by default will draw you a piecewise linear function, i.e. connect the points with line segments). So you might want to increase the number of points from `7` to something larger, like `50`.

NO wait, there's also a slight problem: you should have `.*` instead of `*` in the definition of `x`, like every other operation is also prepended with a `.` (to make those operations element-wise array operations).

AND you have to `plot(y,x)` as that seems to be the order of your function: `y` is independent and `x` is the value of the function.

Fixed version:

```
y=linspace(0,3,50);
x=(y)./((4*3.14*10.^-7).*(1+(4200./(1+0.03*y.^8.2).^0.5)));
plot(y,x)
xlabel('y')
ylabel('x(y)'); %for clarity
```

Result:

[image: plot]